# Windows phone 8.1 ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder Size limit?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, application-data

I am developing windows phone 8.1 runtime application, I need to store mp3 files in local folder of app, to avoid access to user.

But to do this Is there any **size** restrictions or **file count** restriction to store files on local storage.

any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of any published limits as apps can store video streams, etc. In theory, you could fill up to the total storage of the device.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Yes got link saying there in no size restrictions for windows 8 store app development. It should be applicable here though no documents about file count.